# How to validate email address in Wordpress with Ninja Form plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email-validation

I'm trying to find a solution to only validate emails with .edu extension in Wordpress using Ninja Forms plugin.

With Contact Form 7 I can something like this:

```
function is_edu($email) {  
  if(substr($email, -4) == '.edu') {  
       return true;  
  } else {  
       return false;  
  };  
};  
function custom_email_validation_filter($result, $tag) {  
  $type = $tag['type'];  
  $name = $tag['name'];  
  if($name == 'your-email') { // Only apply to fields with the form field name of "your-email"  
       $the_value = $_POST[$name];  
       if(!is_edu($the_value)){  
            $result['valid'] = false;  
            $result['reason'][$name] = 'This is not a .edu address!'; // Error message  
       };  
  };  
   return $result;  
};  
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email','custom_email_validation_filter', 10, 2); // Email field  
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email*', 'custom_email_validation_filter', 10, 2); // Required Email field
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex you can use :

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-z0-9]+@[a-zA-z0-9]+\.edu$/', $emailaddress)) {
  //valid email address, start script
}
```

I imagien you know how to implement this into the plugin ?

Comment: Thanks but no I don't know how to implement this into the Ninja Forms plugin

Comment: God it's a massive plugin....what file does the form send to ? If you dont know, just dump the form html code

Comment: Thanks for the help! Here's the form html dump. This is the reference doc the Ninja-Form guys pointed me to also.

http://pastebin.com/M79dHfPL
http://ninjaforms.com/documentation/ninja_forms_pre_process/